# How to set xlim/ylim with plotly imshow?

Tags: python, plotly

I'm having trouble defining the x and y plot ranges when using the Plotly imshow function.

Here's some randomly generated data and defined plot limits:

```
import numpy as np
img = np.random.randn(400,400)
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = 100, 200, 250, 350
```

with matplotlib, I can do the following to plot the data and set the x and y plot limits:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
ax.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
ax.set_ylim(ymax, ymin)
```

Which yields:

[image]

But with Plotly, when I try to accomplish the same with this code:

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.imshow(
    img,
    color_continuous_scale='gray',
)

fig.update_xaxes(range=[xmin, xmax])
fig.update_yaxes(range=[ymax, ymin])
fig.show()
```

Only the x-axis is scaling appropriately. This is what I get:
[image]

How can I properly set the x and y limits for my plot with plotly?

edit: I'm using Plotly version 5.3.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mentioned that you needed a color scale, so I tried various things and confirmed that if I deactivated autorange, the desired scale and color bar would be displayed.

```
import numpy as np
img = np.random.randn(400,400)
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = 100, 200, 250, 350

import plotly.express as px
fig = px.imshow(
    img,
    color_continuous_scale='gray',
)

fig.update_xaxes(range=[xmin, xmax])
fig.update_yaxes(range=[ymin, ymax], autorange=False)

fig.show()
```

[image]

I don't have the knowledge to explain this, but you can add the following parameters to get the desired square graph. Here is the description from the official reference.

```
fig = px.imshow(img, binary_string=True)
```

> Passing image data as a binary string
> introduced in plotly.py 4.10

> px.imshow can pass the data to the figure object either as a list of numerical values, or as a png binary string which is passed directly to the browser. While the former solution offers more flexibility (values can be of float or int type, while values are rescaled to the range [0-255] for an image string), using a binary string is usually faster for large arrays. The parameter binary_string controls whether the image is passed as a png string (when True) or a list of values (False). Its default value is True for multi-channel images and False for single-channel images. When binary_string=True, image data are always represented using a go.Image trace.

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.imshow(
    img,
    #color_continuous_scale='gray',
    binary_string=True
)

fig.update_xaxes(range=[xmin, xmax])
fig.update_yaxes(range=[ymax, ymin])
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: See this: [reference](https://plotly.com/python/imshow/#passing-image-data-as-a-binary-string)

Comment: Thanks @r-beginners. You're right that the `binary_string=True` keyword arg allows the y-axis to be scaled. But it then makes it impossible to declare a colormap (e.g. `color_continuous_scale='balance'`). This feels like more of a workaround than a solution. I'm going to wait and see if any other solutions pop up before marking this as the answer.

Comment: Answer updated in response to comments. If the first answer is not needed, it will be removed. I've been doing some research and it is usually treated as a heatmap, but if `binary_string=True`, it is defined as an image.

Comment: You're updated answer is perfect! `autorange=False` is the solution. Thanks so much!